# An analytic function with minimum and maximum at the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose there is a complex valued function analytic on some open connected set U and continuous on the boundary of that set. Then the maximum of $|f|$ is attained at some point on the boundary. Say $Max|f|=2$. Now suppose for some point on the boundary $|f|=0$. If so can there be a point in U such that $|f|=0$?I know by using the open mapping theorem that there can't be such a point. But isn't there another way to prove that $|f|$ cannot be $0$ in $U$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=z(1-z)$. $f$ is analytic on $U=\{|z|<1\}$, continuous on $\{|z|\le1\}$ and $|f(0)|=0$, $|f(1)|=0$, with $0\in U$ and $1\in\partial U$.

Comment: How come this does not contradict the open mapping theorem?

Comment: What would the contradiction be?

Comment: image of a open set say A cannot be mapped to boundary points of f(A) right? isn't 0 a boundary point of the image?

Comment: $0$ is not a boundary point of $f(U)$.

Comment: The open mapping theorem implies that if $f(z)$ is in the boundary of $f(U)$ then $z$ is in the boundary of $U$.